# Ergodic theorem for finite Markov chains

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)$ be a finite Markov chain.
$R_i$, $i = 1,\dots, l$ are the recurrent classes with invariant probability $\pi_i$.
For all $i \in 1,\dots, l$ define $\tau_i = \inf \{n\geq 1 | X_n\in R_i\}$.
$f$ is a bounded function.

Then $\mathbb{P}$-as $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n f(X_k) \to \sum_{i=1}^l \mathbb{1}(\tau_i<\infty)\int fd\pi_i$ as $n\to +\infty$.

I cannot find a proof of this theorem, can someone give a reference or a demonstration?